# Azure build pipeline suddenly fails with a framework-not-found-error although .NET 5.0 is installed

Tags: .net, .net-core, build, azure-pipelines

The Azure build pipeline for a repo that was not touched for some time now suddenly fails with a message that .NET 5.0 cannot be found (details see below). .NET 5.0 is installed on the (self-hosted azure agent) build machine and when I check the file system it is exactly at the expected location.

But the pipeline's error message lists all available frameworks there and none of the 3 installed 5.0. frameworks are found. Other deprecated frameworks like 3.1. are listed.

Pipeline's error message:

```
##[error]Testhost process for source(s) 'D:\a\1\s\xxx.dll' exited with error: You must install or update .NET to run this application.
##[error]App: D:\a\1\s\xxx\bin\Release\net5.0\testhost.exe
##[error]Architecture: x64
##[error]Framework: 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '5.0.0' (x64)
##[error].NET location: C:\Program Files\dotnet
##[error]The following frameworks were found:
##[error]  3.1.4 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
##[error]  3.1.6 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
##[error]  3.1.20 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
##[error]  3.1.32 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
##[error]  6.0.5 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
##[error]  6.0.16 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
##[error]  7.0.5 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
##[error]Learn about framework resolution:
##[error]https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed
##[error]To install missing framework, download:
##[error]https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=5.0.0&arch=x64&rid=win10-x64
##[error]. Please check the diagnostic logs for more information.
```

Proof 1 that the framework is installed:

`DIR "C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App"`

```
 Directory of C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App

27.04.2023  18:23    <DIR>          .
27.04.2023  18:23    <DIR>          ..
21.08.2021  04:08    <DIR>          2.1.30
23.10.2021  04:17    <DIR>          3.1.20
12.11.2022  05:02    <DIR>          3.1.31
04.02.2023  05:11    <DIR>          3.1.32
21.05.2022  04:15    <DIR>          5.0.17
13.03.2021  05:11    <DIR>          5.0.4
21.08.2021  04:08    <DIR>          5.0.9
14.11.2022  17:47    <DIR>          6.0.11
18.01.2023  17:42    <DIR>          6.0.13
27.04.2023  18:22    <DIR>          6.0.16
18.01.2023  17:43    <DIR>          7.0.2
27.04.2023  18:23    <DIR>          7.0.5
```

Proof 2 that the framework is installed:

`dotnet --list-runtimes`

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.20 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.31 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.32 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.16 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.20 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.31 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.32 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.16 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.20 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.31 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.32 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.16 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 7.0.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 7.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

Proof 3 that the framework is installed:

`dotnet sdk check`

```
.NET SDKs:
Version      Status
----------------------------------------
3.1.120      .NET 3.1 is out of support.
3.1.426      .NET 3.1 is out of support.
5.0.104      .NET 5.0 is out of support.
5.0.214      .NET 5.0 is out of support.
5.0.303      .NET 5.0 is out of support.
5.0.414      .NET 5.0 is out of support.
7.0.102      Patch 7.0.105 is available.
7.0.203      Up to date.
```

Any ideas? Is there a Windows-policy that might have disabled certain out-of-support frameworks?